# Why does class name of a type in a package object contain "package" in runtime class name?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to generate the runtime class name of a class that is defined in a `package object`.

Example:

```
package com.foo

package object bar {
  case class MyCaseClass()

}

import bar._
MyCaseClass().getClass.getCanonicalName
```

The above will generate `com.foo.bar.package.MyCaseClass`

If I use `WeakTypeTag` it will correctly generate the type as `com.foo.bar.MyCaseClass`.

```
package com.foo

trait MyTrait
case class MyImpl extends MyTrait

def getType[T](t: T)(implicit weakTypeTag WeakTypeTag[T]): String = {
   weakTypeTag.tpe.fullName
}
```

What is the reason for the above difference in behavior? I know I must be missing something about the Scala type system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't so much about the type system as about the encoding of package objects on the JVM. The JVM doesn't have package-level methods, for example, so the Scala compiler has to create a synthetic class that has static methods, inner classes, etc. corresponding to the definitions in the package object. That class is named `package`, an arbitrary but self-explanatory name that has the advantage of being a keyword in both Scala and Java, so it's unlikely to result in collisions with non-synthetic code.

Java's reflection APIs know nothing about Scala, so naturally they can't hide this encoding from you. When you call `getClass.getCanonicalName` you're seeing the actual class name, corresponding to the class file you'd find at `com/foo/bar/package\$MyCaseClass.class` when you compile your code.

Scala's reflection APIs do know about Scala's encoding of package objects, and they will hide the synthetic `package` class from you. This arguably makes sense, since the details of the encoding aren't in the spec (if I remember correctly?) and so may vary across platforms or language versions, etc.

The discrepancy is a little confusing, but this isn't the only time you'll run into differences—the Scala reflection API hides lots of mangling, etc. that Java reflection can't.